# How to change user status "not_invited" to "active" by Bim 360 API

Tags: autodesk-bim360

I'm trying to manage user account by BIM 360 API.
I could add user by the api but I don't know how to switch the status "not invited" to "active".
Please tell me if you know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this functionality is not available from the API, the activation of the user needs to be performed by the invitation sent to the user added to the account.